# What is the PHP Imagick class equivalent to the convert -auto-orient commandline switch

Tags: php, imagick, exif

I currently use [Imagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) directly by doing a `convert -auto-orient` system call within my PHP file to autorotate images based on [EXIF data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif). For consistency reasons I would like to use the [PHP Imagick class](http://php.net/manual/de/book.imagick.php). Is there any function equivalent to the [auto-orient commandline option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing straight out of the box that does this. Here's a method I always use to auto rotate an image.

```
function resample($jpgFile, $thumbFile, $width, $orientation) {
    // Get new dimensions
    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($jpgFile);
    $height = (int) (($width / $width_orig) * $height_orig);
    // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image   = imagecreatefromjpeg($jpgFile);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
    // Fix Orientation
    switch($orientation) {
        case 3:
            $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 180, 0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, -90, 0);
            break;
        case 8:
            $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 90, 0);
            break;
    }
    // Output
    imagejpeg($image_p, $thumbFile, 90);
}
```